# Two-piece normal distribution in Stata

Tags: stata

The overall variance and skewness of Two-piece Normal (TPN) is given by:

() = <sub>1</sub> <sub>2</sub> + (1 − <sup>2</sup>)(<sub>2</sub> − <sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>

() = (<sub>2</sub> − <sub>1</sub>)[(2<sup>2</sup> − 1)(<sub>2</sub> − <sub>1</sub>)^2 + <sub>1</sub><sub>2</sub>]

where  = 2/pi

For given values of () and (), two variances (<sub>1</sub> and <sub>2</sub>) could be estimated. How can I set up this nonlinear simultaneous equations problem in STATA? Any help?

Comment: edit k = sqrt(2/pi)

Comment: See Stata FAQ: https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/system-of-nonlinear-equations/

Comment: Thanks JR96. Actually, I have tried this method, but it returns error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @TassJam I suggest editing your post to include the code you tried so we can help with the specific error.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got some help on Stata List. The solution is here (https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1655384-two-piece-normal-distribution).